# Add new Css Style in SharePoint Designer

Tags: css, sharepoint, designer

I am trying to customize one field of a discussion forum in SharePoint, basically i want 
to resize (maker bigger) the body Field.

I think this can be done applying a new css specific to that field but i am not sure how to do this, becuase it's seem that some other css are overlapping the one that  i created and that’s why mine is not applied.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a !important after the css rule?
like

```
.bodytxt
{
height: 300px !important;
}
```

Comment: Check with Firefox (Firebug) to see if the css rule is being applied and if its being overriden.